# Value does not fall within the expected range GeoboundingBox WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, bing-maps

im trying to fit 2 pois on a bing map for WinRT Universal APP, commonly user position and any other point, so the user can see the map between two points, i have this code:

```
private void centerMap(Geoposition pos, MapPoi pos2)
    {
        try { 
    #if WINDOWS_APP
            //TODO PC Maps
    #elif WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        GeoboundingBox geoboundingBox = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeoboundingBox(
        new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = pos.Coordinate.Latitude, Longitude = pos.Coordinate.Longitude },
        new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = pos2.lat, Longitude = pos2.lng });
        map1._map.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(geoboundingBox,null,MapAnimationKind.Linear);
    #endif
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    }
```

So one more time i have a problem i cannot solve myself.

First i need to understand something that i must be doing bad, im getting System.ArgumentException on the GeoboundingBox constructor, here stack trace:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EspartAPP.WindowsPhone.exe
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeoboundingBox..ctor(BasicGeoposition northwestCorner, BasicGeoposition southeastCorner)
   at EspartAPP.Modulos.Modulo_Mapa.centerMap(Geoposition pos, MapPoi pos2)
```

Here are the coordinates used for the test:

```
pos var: Lat 40.4564664510315 lng -3.65939843190291
pos2 var: Lat 40.4579103 lngs -3.6532357
```

Both coordinates are correct, one is the user position just got from gps, the other is a close location.

I cant understand what can be going bad, there must be something that i need to know.

The code i posted just throw that exception, but, if i just do +1 to the pos latitude it works, and seems to be doing it right.

If i add pos2 first (as northwestCorner) it doesnt throw exception, it zooms out to max so i can almost see the entire map (which is obviously wrong)

There must be some rules im ignoring, **maybe i have to calc which coordinate should be on northwest position?**

**EDIT: Was exactly that, working code:**

```
 private void centerMap(Geoposition pos, MapPoi pos2)
    {
        try {
            BasicGeoposition nw = new BasicGeoposition();
            nw.Latitude = Math.Max(pos.Coordinate.Latitude, pos2.lat);
            nw.Longitude = Math.Min(pos.Coordinate.Longitude, pos2.lng);
            BasicGeoposition se = new BasicGeoposition();
            se.Latitude = Math.Min(pos.Coordinate.Latitude, pos2.lat);
            se.Longitude = Math.Max(pos.Coordinate.Longitude, pos2.lng);


    #if WINDOWS_APP
            //TODO PC Maps
    #elif WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        GeoboundingBox geoboundingBox = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeoboundingBox(nw,se);
        map1._map.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(geoboundingBox,null,MapAnimationKind.Bow);
    #endif
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english and problems with this bing maps, this is really poor documented i expect because its the newer API and its a mess to find what you need for the API you are working for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not providing the correct coordinates. As you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn607953.aspx) the first coordinate must be upper left corner of the region (the north west coordinate), the second must be the lower right corner (the south east coordinate). Your `pos` is the lower left corner and `pos2` is the upper right corner.

You get the right coordinates like this:

```
var nw = new BasicGeoposition();
nw.Latitude = Max(pos.Coordinate.Latitude, pos2.lat);
nw.Longitude = Min(pos.Coordinate.Longitude, pos2.lng);
var se = new BasicGeoposition();
se.Latitude = Min(pos.Coordinate.Latitude, pos2.lat);
se.Longitude = Max(pos.Coordinate.Longitude, pos2.lng);
```

Comment: So i was right, i'll give it a try thanks for the code.